# Why can't you implement traits for external types by using type aliases?

Tags: rust

I understand you cannot implement the `Default` trait for types not implemented in the current crate. Why can you not alias those types to an internally used type and do it?

This doesn't work ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d27f6bcfffe97e06bfbfc7133712ad60)):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub type MyPortMappings = HashMap<&'static str, (u32, &'static str)>;

impl Default for MyPortMappings {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("ftp", (21, "File Transfer Protocol"));
        m.insert("http", (80, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol"));
        m
    }
}
```

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate
 --> src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
5 | impl Default for MyPortMappings {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------
  | |                |
  | |                `HashMap` is not defined in the current crate
  | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
  |
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Would it not make sense to implement defaults under own control?

Comment: Type aliases are like textual replacement. They do not create a new type. Use a newtype instead.

Comment: Because `MyPortMappings` is the same type as `HashMap<…>` so it has the same limitations. If you want to implement `Default` (or anything else) for it, you will have to use the [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html).

Comment: Thank you. How do I create a newtype for HashMap, without using an alias?

Comment: `struct Newtype(HashMap<...>);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s because type aliases are just aliases, not separate types. You'll need to create your own wrapper using `struct`, `enum` or `union`.

Here's an alternative using the [newtype](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html) idiom:

```rust
pub struct MyPortMappings(HashMap<&'static str, (u32, &'static str)>);

impl MyPortMapping {
    // ... boilerplate and associated items...
}

impl Default for MyPortMappings {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("ftp", (21, "File Transfer Protocol"));
        m.insert("http", (80, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol"));
        Self(m)
    }
}
```

You can also use the [Delegate](https://crates.io/crates/delegate) crate to delegate methods of a field to the struct itself.

But in your case it's better just to implement a function that would return needed value, or create a trait if you need it to be a method. Creating another type is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Awesome. How do I now type-erase the newtype so that I can call members of the HashMap? I want to do  MyPortMappings::default().iter() but MyPortMappings doesn't have iter().

Comment: Implement it yourself of delegate the methods using Delegate crate (i left it's URL in my answer)

Comment: Sure, that would work. Is there a simpler, more idiomatic way to auto-propagate calls instead of this indirection? If not, would the compiler optimize the indirection out so that directly the correct method is called?

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired. I had a look at the Delegate crate. What about the indirection penalty?

Comment: Yes, compiler would optimize it because of `#[inline(always)]`. And yes, there’s a proper way that I already mentioned - not creating a new type, just create a function that would return needed value!

Comment: Btw, if you really need another type, you can implement `Deref` and `DerefMut` with original HashMap as `Target`. Deref coercion allows you to call methods of a needed type.